# preparing two df for prediction; predictor is string, numbers are in second df; dictionary, map in machine learning?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, prediction

I want to predict "score" from df "A" using "1,2,3,4,5" as predictors. Goal is to mix up 5 new predictors/names and get the dependent variable "score". The numbers behind each independent variable are in df "B". There are about 300 names/predictors in different combinations in df "A", number of rows 2500.

I thought about a dictionary, nested variable. I added the numbers from df "B" already using map and dictionary but in a form not suitable for the prediction (additional columns behind score). What could be the best way to set up/combine these two df for a prediction model?

df "A"

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1':['Tom','Peter', 'Frank'],
        '2':['Julius', 'Zach', 'Thomas'],
               '3':['Ervin', 'Larry', 'Devin'],
       '4':['Nigel', 'Frank', 'John' ],
       '5': ['Jalen', 'Jamar', 'Phil'],
       'Score': [2, 3, 1]}
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
print(df)
   
      1       2      3      4      5      Score
0    Tom  Julius  Ervin  Nigel  Jalen      2
1  Peter    Zach  Larry  Frank  Jamar      3
2  Frank  Thomas  Devin   John   Phil      1
```

df "B"

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Tom','Peter', 'Frank', 'Julius', 'Zach', 'Thomas', 'Ervin', 'Larry', 'Devin', 'Nigel', 'Frank', 'John', 'Jalen', 'Jamar', 'Phil'],
        'A':[0.75, 0.78, 0.91, 0.54, 0.92, 0.88, 0.81, 0.23, 0.25, 0, 0.71, 0.64, 0, 0, 0.82 ],
               'B':[0.34, 0.43, 0.55, 0.65, 0.21, 0.98, 0.77, 0, 0.67, 0.78, 0.12, 0.22, 0, 0.76, 0],
       'C':[0.91, 0.64, 0.33, 0.50, 0.75, 0.89, 0.82, 0.72, 0.62, 0.87, 0.21, 0.45, 0.56, 0, 0],
       'D': [0.12, 0.33, 0.65, 0.79, 0.41, 0.78, 0.66, 0.82, 0.74, 0.81, 0, 0.51, 0.44, 0, 0.73],
       'E': [ 0.50, 0.65, 0.98, 0.91, 0.51, 0.42, 0.38, 0.85, 0.21, 0.67, 0, 0.53, 0, 0.48, 0.69]}
 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
 

print(df2)

      Name     A     B     C     D     E
0      Tom  0.75  0.34  0.91  0.12  0.50
1    Peter  0.78  0.43  0.64  0.33  0.65
2    Frank  0.91  0.55  0.33  0.65  0.98
3   Julius  0.54  0.65  0.50  0.79  0.91
4     Zach  0.92  0.21  0.75  0.41  0.51
5   Thomas  0.88  0.98  0.89  0.78  0.42
6    Ervin  0.81  0.77  0.82  0.66  0.38
7    Larry  0.23  0.00  0.72  0.82  0.85
8    Devin  0.25  0.67  0.62  0.74  0.21
9    Nigel  0.00  0.78  0.87  0.81  0.67
10   Frank  0.71  0.12  0.21  0.00  0.00
11    John  0.64  0.22  0.45  0.51  0.53
12   Jalen  0.00  0.00  0.56  0.44  0.00
13   Jamar  0.00  0.76  0.00  0.00  0.48
14    Phil  0.82  0.00  0.00  0.73  0.69
```

Possible Outcome?

```
      1       2      3      4      5      Score   Tom A Tom B ....  Julius A
                                                                 
0  Tom  Julius  Ervin  Nigel  Jalen        2      0.75   0.34       0.54
1  Peter    Zach  Larry  Frank  Jamar      3
2  Frank  Thomas  Devin   John   Phil      1
```

Comment: Read your questions many times but still don't get what do you want to do with these two dataframes. Do you want to add `Score` column in `df1` to `df2`?

Comment: Columns 1-5 in df 1 predict column "score" but basically columns A,B,C,D;E in df 2 are the numbers predicting "score"via columns 1-5  in df 1.

Comment: Tom in df 1is basically: 0.75, 0.34, 0.91, 0.12, 0.50
Julius: 0.54, 0.65, 0.50. 079, 0.91

Comment: But I need to keep the string/names. Later on I want to add 5 random names and get the result for "score".

Comment: I edited a possible option to create one ore more cols withe values from df B. Not sure if this would work with prediction, modeling.